# VB.Net Task.WaitAll with Timeout Cancellation Request

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I know there are a few threads and atricles about this arouynd but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Basically I have two (or more) tasks that I want to run but with a timeout and after this timeout I want all tasks to cancel and have a way to know that we've timed out so I can return this to my web page.

Here's what I have:

```
Dim cts As System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource = New System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource

Dim oTask1 As Task(Of SearchReturn) = Task(Of SearchReturn).Factory.StartNew(
                         Function()
                             While Not cts.IsCancellationRequested
                                 cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                                 Return Test1(oTest)
                             End While
                         End Function, cts.Token)

Dim oTask2 As Task(Of SearchReturn) = Task(Of SearchReturn).Factory.StartNew(
                         Function()
                             While Not cts.IsCancellationRequested
                                 cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                                 Return Test2(oTest)
                             End While
                         End Function, cts.Token)

If Not Task.WaitAll({oTask1, oTask2}, 4000, cts.Token) Then cts.Cancel()
```

cts.Cancel() does get called so it knows it's taken too long but it's not actually cancelling it, it just carries on until the tasks have finished.

I'm sure it's probably something simple I'm doing wrong but I jsut can't spot it.

Thanks in advance.
Andy

Comment: If `Test1` and `Test2` aren't written to support cancellation, you're out of luck - cancellation is *cooperative* - the code that's running has to be aware of it. And your `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` lines are *unreachable* since they come after a `Return` statement.

Comment: So do I need to pass cts through to my Test1 and Test2 functions and check cts.IsCancellationRequested in there?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to pass `cts` - but maybe the *token* that it produces (if you pass a `CancellationTokenSource` around then *anyone* can request cancellation using it - whereas more normally you want your outer code to have that level of control but everything else just being able to react to the token).